# How to make the button immovable when rendering a side nav in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a side navigation panel and it is being rendered correctly from the side. But my issue is that when it is rendering from the side, the toggle button (MoreDetails) is moving along.
I want it to remain stationary and just do the toggling.
The code is as follows in navigation.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" >

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" (opened)="events.push('open!')"
               (closed)="events.push('close!')">
   <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item> Oil </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item> Paprika </mat-list-item>
       </mat-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">More Details</button></p>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `mode='"over"'` to render the sidenav "over" the primary content. `mode="side"` put the primary content side by side with the sidenav and shrink the content.

[Material DOcs - Sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#changing-the-sidenav-39-s-behavior)